# Why does dbgview drop previous lines of messages?

Tags: windows, debugging

I use dbgview on some platform to capture log.
But those dbgview output always truncate previous lines of message.
The important information is in those lines.

Is any option to make dbgview capture all the lines?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a new feature added in new version of dbgview.

Don't know why there is a default depth is set on some platforms.
So the dbgview always keeps certain lines of text.

### How to disable:

1. Menu>Options>History Depth or Ctrl + H
2. Reset to 0.

To read documentation is very important.